# delete a list of index from a list

Tags: python, list

So I've got into trouble when I want to delete a sequence of index from a list

```
    for i in linked_node:
        del l[i]
```

the linked_node is the index sequence 
this code simply wont work cause del changed the size of the list

using a for loop , I can do this by appending them to a new list

```
  l1 = []      
  for i in range(len(l)):
     if i is not in linked_node:
         l1.append(l[])
```

my question is , how to do this in an elegent way?without creating another list

Comment: Are you looping over the list itself or not? Because your code says one thing, but your error description says another.

Comment: Either you are looping over `l` and are deleting while looping over it (which won't work without creating a copy) *or* you are looping over a list of indices.

Comment: You'll need to show us more code for us to give you any meaningful help here.

Comment: thanks, I edited it to make it more specific

Comment: btw. 'del l[i]' will fail because you don't put in the index of you listitem, but the item itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to create a new list, as in @Haidro's solution, but really delete the elements at the given indices from the *existing* list, you could also reverse the list of indices, so that indices at the end of the list are deleted first.

```
for i in sorted(linked_node, reverse=True):
    del l[i]
```

Otherwise, the elements you want to delete will shift to the left as you delete elements, thus changing their indices, and you end up deleting the wrong elements, or getting an `IndexError`.

Comment: yeah, haidro's solution also creat a new list, but in a more elegent way

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
>>> l = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey', 'hai']
>>> indexes = {1, 2}
>>> [j for i, j in enumerate(l) if i not in indexes]
['hi', 'hai']
```

Comment: `indexes = set([1, 2])`

Comment: @hughdbrown Changed :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
linked_node.sort(reversed=True)
for i in linked_node:
  del l[i]
```

Now this should work because the indices you are interested in stay the same.
Another way to do it, if it's already sorted:

```
for (x, i) in enumerate(linked_node):
  del l[i - x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using the reversed iteration trick, but somewhat faster because you don't have to sort your list:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for idx in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
    i = l[idx]
    print(i)
    if i in ["b", "d", "c"]:
        del(l[idx])
print(l) 

>>> d
>>> c
>>> b
>>> a
>>> ['a']
```